# Checking an input in python

Tags: python, input

Basically, I'm asking for an input, which is going to be `split(',')` however, if the person doesn't input it properly, for example they accidentally input just `5,` or don't include a comma at all, it comes up with an error that something is undefined.

Does anyone have any idea of how to check that the input is in the right sort of format?

Edit: Here's the code in question...it's to do with coordinates

```
def EnterCoords():
    coordinates = input("Enter coordinates in the following format x,y").split(',')
    x, y = Coordinates[0], Coordinates[1]
```

I then use the x and y values in a calculation elsewhere, which brings up the error `IndexError: list index out of range` So, if the user enters them wrong, is there a way of calling the function again, for them to try again

Comment: show the actual error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll be much more likely to get a useful answer if you can include some code and the error you're seeing.

Comment: I'm honestly sick of SO shutting down perfectly good questions. To OP: catch the `ValueError`. It's hard to know precisely if the text is formatted the way you want it until `split()` actually runs.

Comment: are you using input or raw_input?

Comment: The question appears to be about defensive programming in general (focused a bit on the problem of input validation / sanitization). I don't think it is about a single, specific error. It actually seems like a reasonable question to me as-is. Well answered by a simple try-except example, and a discussion of why defensive programming is bad in a dynamically typed language (and in general too).

Comment: Instead of checking for a specific format, try searching for a specific values:

    `data = raw_input('Enter a few values: ') # let's say 1, 3, 4.5, 5,
    nums = []
    
    for entry in re.findall('[0-9.]+', data):
        nums.append(float(entry))
    
    print nums # now just numbers regardless of commas`

Answer (score 2):

Given your updated question, then the best way is to use a `try`/`except`.

```
def enter_coords():
    while True:
        try:
            # Use `raw_input` for Python 2.x
            x, y = input('Enter coordinates ...: ').split(',')
            return int(x), int(y) # maybe use `float` here?
        except ValueError as e:
            pass
```

Keep looping until a successful return. By using `x, y =` - you're requesting that only two values should be unpacked (less or more will raise a `ValueError`), if that succeeds, then you try to return the `int` equivalent of those values, again, if they're not suitables `int`s, then you get a `ValueError`... you then ignore that error and the loop repeats until a successful return executes.

More general approaches and the principles of using this approach are detailed in the excellent: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: think you are missing a try :P

Comment: @Padraic *looks embarrassed* - thanks... still needed the `while True` there though :p

Comment: ah fix one thing break another sounds familiar :)

Comment: In python 3 there's the neat supress condtion, `from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(Exception):` which will ignore the exception, it replaces the try/except: pass

Comment: @f.rodrigues it's a useful thing to know about, however in this case, it's not really applicable

Comment: Isn't? Put it inside the while loop and break once got the valid input? I haven't test it, I don't have python3 in my machine. I was curious about it.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Just realized you're not looking for alpha only string.

---

To **check for commas** use any of the following:
There are multiple ways of solving this problem:

**Using `in` operator**

Check for a comma in the string using the `in` operator:

```
if "," in str:
 <code on true condition>
```

Example:

```
In [8]: if "," in "Hello World!":
   ...:     print "Contains Comma"
   ...:     

In [9]: if "," in "Hello,World":
   ...:     print "Contains Comma"
   ...:     
Contains Comma
```

-OR-

**Exception Handling**

You could use `try ... except` block to check for error when ',' is not present in string as suggested by James Taylor. 
See documentation for handling exceptions: 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

-OR-

**RegEx**

As suggested by Malik Brahimi in the comments - "Instead of checking for a specific format, try searching for a specific values":

```
data = raw_input('Enter a few values: ') # let's say 1, 3, 4.5, 5,
nums = []

for entry in re.findall('[0-9.]+', data):
    nums.append(float(entry))

print nums # now just numbers regardless of commas
```

Comment: I believe regex is another valid way of solving the OP's problem. Your edit is worthy to be an independent answer. Kindly add one to augment the discussion.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude, the topic's been put on hold, and you seem to be accumulating downvotes. I thought my answer might be of use to you.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification Malik, I will incorporate your answer. Secondly, that downvote was well deserved - due to misunderstanding of the OP's question which I've corrected since.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, don't be too hard on yourself.